# Why Doesn't My Board Appear when creating connect four?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a GUI Java Code of Connect Four, however none of my game Board circles appear. I have drawn them onto the board however they just don't show up. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Please help and see revised code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
//how do I get the board to actually appear?


public class JenniferConnectFourJan19 {

  static int [][] boardArray = new int [6][7];
  static String [][] spotOnBoard = new String [6][7];
  static int maxRow=6;
  static int maxCol=7;
  static boolean endOfGame = false;
  static boolean gameStart;

  static JPanel boardPanel;

  static JButton firstOption = new JButton ("Drop");
  static JButton secondOption = new JButton ("Drop");
  static JButton thirdOption = new JButton ("Drop");
  static JButton fourthOption = new JButton ("Drop");
  static JButton fifthOption = new JButton ("Drop");
  static JButton sixthOption = new JButton ("Drop");
  static JButton seventhOption = new JButton ("Drop");

  static JButton playAgain = new JButton ("New");
  static JButton reset = new JButton ("Reset");
  static JButton exit = new JButton ("Exit");

  static int blank =0;
  static int red=1;
  static int yellow=2;
  static int firstColour= red;

  public static void board() {
    boardArray = new int [maxRow][maxCol];
    for (int row=0; row < maxRow; row++){
      for (int col=0; col< maxCol; col++){
        boardArray[row][col]= blank;
      }
    }
  }


  public static class drawBoard extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
      super.paintComponent(g);
 //     drawBoard(g, drawBoard); 
  }//end of paintComponent.

  void drawConnectFourBoard(Graphics g){    

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(110, 50, 100+100*maxCol, 100+100*maxRow);
    for (int row=0; row<maxRow; row++)
      for (int col=0; col<maxCol; col++) {
      if (boardArray[row][col]==blank) g.setColor(Color.white);
      if (boardArray[row][col]==red) g.setColor(Color.red);
      if (boardArray[row][col]==yellow) g.setColor(Color.yellow);
      g.fillOval(160+100*col, 100+100*row, 100, 100);
    }
  }
  public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(300,300);
  }
  }

  public static boolean winCheck(String box) { 
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) { 
      for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) { 
        if(spotOnBoard[j][k].equals(box)) {           
          if(((j -3) >= 0) && spotOnBoard[j -1][k].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j -2][k].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j -3][k].equals(box)) {  
            return true;
          }          
          else if(((k -3) >= 0) && spotOnBoard[j][k -1].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j][k -2].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j][k -3].equals(box)) {
            return true; 
          }          
          else if(((j+3)<= 5) && spotOnBoard[j+1][k].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j+2][k].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j+3][k].equals(box)){ 
            return true;
          }          
          else if(((k +3) <= 6) && spotOnBoard[j][k +1].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j][k +2].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j][k +3].equals(box)) {          
            return true; 
          }          
          else if(((j -3)>= 0) && ((k +3)<=6) && spotOnBoard[j-1][k+1].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j-2][k+2].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j-3][k+3].equals(box)){ 
            return true; 
          }          
          else if(((j +3) <=5) && ((k -3) >=0) && spotOnBoard[j +1][k -1].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j +2][k -2].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j +3][k -3].equals(box)){ 
            return true;
          }          
          else if(((j -3)>=0) && ((k -3)>= 0) && spotOnBoard[j -1][k -1].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j -2][k -2].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j -3][k -3].equals(box)){ 
            return true;
          }          
          else if(((j +3) <=5) && ((k +3) <=6) && spotOnBoard[j +1][k +1].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j +2][k +2].equals(box) && spotOnBoard[j +3][k +3].equals(box)){
            return true; 
          }
          else 
            return false; 
        }
      } 
    }
    return false; 
  }

  public static void displayWinner(Graphics g, int n) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 100));
    if (n==red)
      g.drawString("Red wins!", 100, 400);
    else
      g.drawString("Yellow wins!", 100, 400);
    endOfGame=true;
  }

  public static void main (String [] args) {
    drawBoard drawConnectFourBoard = new drawBoard();
    board();

    ButtonHandler listen = new ButtonHandler();

    firstOption.addActionListener(listen);
    secondOption.addActionListener(listen);
    thirdOption.addActionListener(listen);
    fourthOption.addActionListener(listen);
    fifthOption.addActionListener(listen);
    sixthOption.addActionListener(listen);
    seventhOption.addActionListener(listen);
    playAgain.addActionListener(listen);
    reset.addActionListener(listen);
    exit.addActionListener(listen);

   // JPanel boardPanel = new JPanel();


    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,7));   
    topPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
    topPanel.add(firstOption);
    topPanel.add(secondOption);
    topPanel.add(thirdOption);
    topPanel.add(fourthOption);
    topPanel.add(fifthOption);
    topPanel.add(sixthOption);
    topPanel.add(seventhOption);


    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
    bottomPanel.add(playAgain);
    bottomPanel.add(reset);
    bottomPanel.add(exit);


    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,214,154));
    mainPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    mainPanel.add(drawConnectFourBoard);
    board();
    mainPanel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JFrame window = new JFrame ("Connect4");
    window.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    window.setSize(500,500);
    window.setLocation(500,100);
    window.setResizable(true);
    window.setVisible(true);
  }

   private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) {
      if (a.getSource()== firstOption)
        dropCircle(1);
      else if (a.getSource()== secondOption)
        dropCircle(2);
      else if (a.getSource()== thirdOption)
        dropCircle(3);
      else if (a.getSource()== fourthOption)
        dropCircle(4);
      else if (a.getSource()== fifthOption)
        dropCircle(5);
      else if (a.getSource()== sixthOption)
        dropCircle(6);
      else if (a.getSource()==seventhOption)
        dropCircle(7);

    if (a.getSource() == playAgain) {
      gameStart=true;
    }
    if (a.getSource() == exit) {
      System.exit(0);
    }
    }   
    public void dropCircle(int n) {
      if (endOfGame) return;
      gameStart=true;
      int row;
      n--;
      for (row=0; row<maxRow; row++)
        if (boardArray[row][n]>0) break;
      if (row>0) {
        boardArray[--row][n]=firstColour;
        if (firstColour==red)
          firstColour=yellow;
        else
          firstColour=red;

      }
    }

   }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post your whole program and force us to slog through tons of code not relevant to your problem, but instead create and post a small, minimal in fact, testable program, an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please click on the link to see what you will want to post.

Comment: I posted it all because without it, nothing would compile properly.

Comment: All you're trying to do is to display images in a GUI, right? Once you figure out how, then you can apply it to your full program. So **create a small program that tries to do just this, that say tries to create an ImageIcon and displays it in a JOptionPane**. This small program should be no more than 20 lines at most, and should compile and run.

Comment: Or, "start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears". For example, this code has 10 buttons. Maybe remove all but one of the buttons?

Comment: For example, please see my first posted small program called "DefaultFoo.java" in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21223371/522444). It has nothing more than a main method that displays an ImageIcon in a JOptionPane.

Comment: As an aside, note that your program grossly over-uses and mis-uses the `static` modifier. None of your JButtons, JPanels, boolean variables should be `static`. If you're making them so to fix a bug, then you fixed it wrong.

Comment: Where are the images stored in relationship to the project?  Are they stored within the source/resources or one the file system relative to where the program is executed...?

Comment: yes they're stored in the same file.

Comment: Ah, I see the reason for your over-use of statics: most of the code in your static main method should be in your class's constructor. The main method should simply create a JenniferConnectFour instance and ask it to display its GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You have a cascade of issues, which aren't going to be easy to solve.

Firstly, the over use of `static` is going not working in your favour, in fact, it's a sign of a bad design.

You can begin to correct this by creating a custom component, extending from something like `JPanel` and using this as the bases for the rest of your application, creating more custom components as you need them, or just using simple containers, like `JPanel`, to produce more complex UIs

Secondly, it "seems" like you have a resource problem.  Generally speaking, you have two types of resources you application can use, external and internal (AKA embedded).

`ImageIcon(String)` is looking for an external resource on your disk (ie a `File`).  Based on your cryptic comments, I would assume that the images are actually embedded within the context of your application, making it impossible for `ImageIcon(String)` to find anything.

Instead, you should try using `ImageIcon(URL)`, for example `new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/path/to/image/image.png")`

The problem with `ImageIcon` is it won't throw an `Exception` when it fails to find or load the image, sometimes simply painting nothing.

Instead, you should be using `ImageIO.read`.  Take a look at [Reading/Loading images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

**Additional**

- There's nothing in your `paintComponent` that actually paints anything
- There's no way for your `ActionListener` to notify anybody that your game model has updated

Separate the game logic and the UI logic, such that the "model" is purely responsible for maintaing the virtual state of the game and notifying interested parties that the model has changed and that the UI portion is simple responsible for rendering the view model.

Then allow the controls to change the state of the model.

Comment: Fixed what?  Are you sure the images are loading?